# Renaming coat colors in R goes wrong with str_detect

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I have a dataset with horses and want to group them based on coat colors. In my dataset more than 140 colors are used, I would like to go back to only a few coat colors and assign the rest to Other. But for some horses the coat color has not been registered, i.e. those are unknown. Below is what the new colors should be. (To illustrate the problem I have an old coat color and a new one. But I want to simply change the coat colors, not create a new column with colors)

| Horse ID | Coatcolor(old) | Coatcolor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | black | Black |
| 2 | bayspotted | Spotted |
| 3 | chestnut | Chestnut |
| 4 | grey | Grey |
| 5 | cream dun | Other |
| 6 |  | Unknown |
| 7 | blue roan | Other |
| 8 | chestnutgrey | Grey |
| 9 | blackspotted | Spotted |
| 10 |  | Unknown |

Instead, I get the data below(second table), where unknown and other are switched.

| Horse ID | Coatcolor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Black |
| 2 | Spotted |
| 3 | Chestnut |
| 4 | Grey |
| 5 | Unknown |
| 6 | Other |
| 7 | Unknown |
| 8 | Grey |
| 9 | Spotted |
| 10 | Other |

I used the following code

```
mydata <- data %>%
  mutate(Coatcolor = case_when(
     str_detect(Coatcolor, "spotted") ~ "Spotted",
     str_detect(Coatcolor, "grey") ~ "Grey",
     str_detect(Coatcolor, "chestnut") ~ "Chestnut",
     str_detect(Coatcolor, "black") ~ "Black",
     str_detect(Coatcolor, "") ~ "Unknown",
     TRUE ~ Coatcolor
  ))
mydata$Coatcolor[!mydata$Coatcolor %in% c("Spotted", "Grey", "Chestnut", "Black", "Unknown")] <- "Other"
```

So what am I doing wrong/missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `recode` function of the`dplyr` package. Assuming the missing spots are `NA`' s, you can then subsequently set all `NA`'s to "Other" with `replace_na` of the `tidyr` package. It depends on the format of your missing data spots.

```
mydata <- tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  coatcol = letters[1:10]
) 

mydata$coatcol[5] <- NA
mydata$coatcol[4] <- ""

mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate_all(list(~na_if(.,""))) %>% # convert empty string to NA
  mutate(Coatcolor_old = replace_na(coatcol, "Unknown")) %>% #set all NA to Unknown
  mutate(Coatcolor_new = recode(
    Coatcolor_old,
    'spotted'= 'Spotted',
    'bayspotted' = 'Spotted',
    'old_name' = 'new_name',
    'a' = 'A', #etc.
  ))
mydata
```

Comment: The missing spots are not NAs though, they are just empty (could be a space in them). coatcolor is of class character btw